# How to create a MAP/PED file from a dosage file on PLINK 2.0

Tags: linux, unix

I am new to PLINK and GWAS studies. I am unsure how to write a script to convert my INFO file or dosage data into a MAP file for an association study between genotype and 1 phenotype. So, first thing: I have an INFO file with dosage information and information on the SNPs, the ID, position, allele 1 and 2 and Information on the imputation (see below)

rs148087467:60523:T:G 60523 T G 0.001 0.161 0.998 0 -1 -1 -1
--- 10:60684:A:C 60684 A C 0.029 0.713 0.978 0 -1 -1 -1

I want to create a script but have no idea how to convert this into a map file. I understand a MAP file has information on the chromosome code, variant identifier (rs), position/genetic distance (morgans) and base-pair co-ordinates (bp units).

I am assuming a ped file will also be generated from this?

Can someone please help me how to create a script! I am so new to all of this, so I do apologise.

Thank you!

Comment: As uninitiated in the PLINK and GWAS studies myself, what is a INFO and MAP file? Are they just plain/raw text files, and you need some script to transform the INFO to a MAP file? Could you phrase your question with an actual input file and a corresponding actual output file that you'd want? (the latter probably being the MAP file)

Comment: The input files are a list of text files from chrom 1 to chrom 23 called oncoarray_chr1.txt_info. The inside looks like this:                                                                           1:10642:G:A 10642 G A 0.001 0.115 0.999 0 -1 -1 -1
--- 1:11008:C:G 11008 C G 0.096 0.299 0.851 0 -1 -1 -1
The output is the bim/bed/fam files that I want to generate using PLINK 2.0.        The map/bim file has the format : Chromosome code, Variant ID, Position in centimorgans, Base-pair coordinate, ALT allele code, REF allele code.

Comment: The idea is that I want to carry an association study with the phenotype and genotype data.

Comment: TBH it's still not clear what your question and its inherent problem is. Why did you tag this with `unix` and `linux`? Unless someone uses the same software and is known in this field, there are few persons who can help with this.

Comment: My research is using the linux/unix system, my area of research is genetics.